# Eloquent multiple column selection with operators

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When querying using Eloquent models we use

```
$modelInsatnce->where([$arrayContainingConditions])
```

to select rows filtered for multiple columns using `=` operator.

And for filtering with custom operators on single column we use,

```
$modelInsatnce->where($column,$operator,$value)
```

How can we filter for multiple columns using custom operators without chained calling?

Answer (score 4):

The `where` function can take an array.  From the Laravel API:

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    // If the column is an array, we will assume it is an array of key-value pairs
    // and can add them each as a where clause. We will maintain the boolean we
    // received when the method was called and pass it into the nested where.
    if (is_array($column)) {
        return $this->addArrayOfWheres($column, $boolean);
    }
```

Then the `addArrayOfWheres` function:

```
protected function addArrayOfWheres($column, $boolean)
{
    return $this->whereNested(function ($query) use ($column) {
        foreach ($column as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key) && is_array($value)) {
                call_user_func_array([$query, 'where'], $value);
            } else {
                $query->where($key, '=', $value);
            }
```

This looks for a numeric key with an array of values, and then calls `->where()` with the array of values.  If it were an associative array, it assumes `=` for the operator as you've said.  But if you pass a standard array, it will call `where` on the query for each record, using the three array values as arguments:

```
$query->where([
    ['foo','!=',0],
    ['bar','<',5]
]);
```

Also note that you can pass and/or as the 4th argument:

```
$query->where([
    ['foo','!=',0],
    ['bar','<',5]
], null, null, 'or');
```

API link: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L449

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's answer was helpful, but it didn't work in my case.
So I moved 'or' to the fourth argument of inner array.
Tested on Laravel 5.5-5.6.

```
$query->where([
    ['foo', 'like', '%something%'],
    ['bar', '<', 5, 'or']   // <-- HERE
]);
```

It will result in:

```
WHERE (`foo` LIKE '%something%' OR `bar` < 5)
```